# How to manage answers directly on email notifications

Tags: php, notifications, email

I would like to know what's the best way to manage answers to email notifications.

eg. The user receive an email notification, and instead of having to click on a link to go on the website and answer it he could directly reply to the email.

Comment: Interesting that you tagged this "php". We know nothing about what you are trying to do. What kind of notifications are you talking about? What is supposed to happen when the user replies or clicks a link?

Comment: For example if you have a ticket system like trac, the user receive a notification when a new message is added to his ticket. My idea was just to catch the answers directly from the reply to the notification. Sorry that wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *Message-ID* header field to uniquely identify each message. If there is a reply on that message, the client should put that message ID in the *In-Reply-To* header field in the reply message. See RFC 2822 for further details.

Answer (score 2):

There's no best way. Depending on what you want to do with the responses, you could as well handle them with thunderbirds message filters ;) .

Put a unique identifier into the subject or the body of the notification that you're sending so that you can identify & classify the email correctly when a user replies by email.

If you want to stick with php: pick up the php pop3 client class from: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/2.html or find a client elsewhere and then just parse your message responses and classify / handle them however you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Stick an id and authentication token in the subject line.

Pipe it into a script that can process it with Procmail

Answer (score 1):

As a learning exercise you could read the php code and Documentation to the drupal module http://drupal.org/project/mailhandler mail handler.  This accepts emails and looks for script like instructions.

The answer above about checking the message id is also very valid.